# lvdisplay shows nothing

Tags: 20.04

I'm trying to expand the volume to the new amount on my hard drive.

In following a tutorial, it's asking me to input

```
$ lvdisplay
```

But when I do I get no output.  If I do `vgdisplay` I get the following

```
$/home/api# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               virtual-machines
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  1
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                0
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <720.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              184319
  Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0   
  Free  PE / Size       184319 / <720.00 GiB
  VG UUID               X55mTt-ZkYG-prrW-w0az-yweS-4ctv-mXPZkj
```

and lastly `pvdisplay` shows this

```
$/home/api# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               virtual-machines
  PV Size               720.00 GiB / not usable 4.98 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              184319
  Free PE               184319
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               qfpyFh-nZV8-EftV-9orr-oTFL-6H9m-tsFhnb
```

Any help would be appreciated.  As I need the lvdisplay to expand the volume

Answer (score 1):

I had to run `lvcreate` in order to get it to display `lvdisplay`